# Constant Class for Browser Driver

Tags: c#, selenium

Is there any method to make a global class for browser driver in selenium, so i can  use this class to initialize driver in each test instead of repeating same method everytime ?

This method what i want to share between tests for once :

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.SetPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Comment: What have you tried, have you tried the class signature 'public class'

Answer (score 0):

To make a class available anywhere, use the method signature

```
public static class CommonTestFunctions
{ ... }
```

The `public` access modifier will allow any object or class access to your class, just put your functions that you use many times in test methods into that class and use it like:

```
//CommonTestFunctions class
public FireFoxOptions InitFireFoxOptions();
{
      FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(); 
      options.SetPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
    options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
 }

//test method 
var fireFoxOptions = CommonTestFunctions.InitFoxFoxOptions();
```

Comment: check my method i don't think will work with you solution

Comment: It should, make sure you add references to the project with your common functions if you have multiple projects

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in the helper class as below.

```
public static class BrowserConfigurationHelper
{
    public static IWebDriver GetDriver()
    {
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.SetPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
        options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        return driver;
    }
}
```

In Each Test method, you can simply call the GetDriver method to do the driver initialization as below

```
var driver = BrowserConfigurationHelper.GetDriver();
```